# Changing PayPal language to English

Tags: paypal, locale

I am using PayPal-express gem and while setting the parameters for PayPal checkout I tried all the below combinations one-by-one but still, the PayPal page was in the French language.

```
      locale: 'US',
      locale: 'en_US',
      locale: 'En',
      locale: 'Es',
      locale: 'en',
      localecode: 'US',
      localecode: 'en_US',
      localecode: 'En',
      localecode: 'Es',
      localecode: 'en',
      lc: 'US',
      lc: 'en_US',
      lc: 'En',
      lc: 'en',
      lc: 'Es',
      locale_code: 'US',
      locale_code: 'en_US',
      locale_code: 'En',
      locale_code: 'en',
      locale_code: 'Es'
```

How can I get the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Please try LOCALECODE=en_US in the SetEC API Call. Then the PayPal checkout page will be in English. Please clear cookies and cache from the web browser. [Click here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/SetExpressCheckout_API_Operation_NVP/) for more information and search for LOCALECODE.